# Using selector to replace all dropdownlist (select) with label

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to replace all the drop down lists with a `p` element or a label that have only the selected option, reason is I want to prepare this for printing without showing the down arrow that is in dropdownlist.

I need to use type selector as the select element have different classes name and no IDs. Problem is I can't seem to get the complete select element when I'm using `$("select")`.

I notice when I use `$("select")` I got different results than using the ID selector in console

```
$("#id") //return
init {context: document, selector: "#2"}
var allInputs =  $("select"); //return
 <select id="2">
<option>Option</option>
<option>Option2</option>
 </select>


allInputs[key].replaceWith("<p>" + text+ "</p>") //so this doesn't work
```

Here's a copy of the JS code

```
var allInputs =  $("select");
if($("#2")==allInputs[0])

{alert("True");}    

$.each( allInputs, function(key, value ) {
var text=value.find("option:selected").text() ;
allInputs[key].replaceWith("<p>" + text+ "</p>");

});
```

Jsfiddle here:

https://jsfiddle.net/abahrani/fzhv41s7/4/

Comment: You may be over-engineering the purpose.  If you want to hide your arrows for printing purposes then do so in a print style sheet or print media condition.

Comment: I agree with klewis. If you want your example to work though, use a selector around value and allInputs[key]: text=$(value).find("option:selected").text() ;
$(allInputs[key]).replaceWith("<p>" + text+ "</p>");

Comment: Thanks @klewis , I actually want the HTML page also matching the printed one as I'm saving this as a PDF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per thmsdnnr comment, I found out the reason

```
allInputs[key].replaceWith("<p>" + text+ "</p>") // doesn't work
```

didn't work because I needed to use the $ sign, when $(allInputs[key]) used. everything worked.

```
$(allInputs[key]).replaceWith("<p>" + text+ "</p>") //works
```

Answer (score 0):

how about use mapping (I did it with an unordered list but you get the idea) run the snippet below

```js
   $('#mybutton').click(function() {
      $("select").map(function() {
          return $(this)
        }).get()
        .forEach(function(element) {
          $('#container').append(
            `<ul><li>
        ${element.val()}<ul>${getOptions(element)}</ul>
      </li></ul>`)
        });

      function getOptions(element) {
        let html = ''
        element.find('option').map(function() {
            return $(this).val();
          }).get()
          .forEach(function(option) {
            html += `<li>${option}</li>`
          });
        return html;
      }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>

  <input type="file">

  <input type="text">
  <select id="2">
    <option>Option</option>
    <option>Option2</option>
  </select>

  <select>
    <option>selector</option>
    <option>Option3</option>
  </select>
  </br>
  <button type="button" id="mybutton">
  print all options
</button>

</form>
<div id="container">
</div>
```